# printing a string in a specific format

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

So I created have a program that basically prints any given string like that:

Example:
Input:

```
Hello
```

Output:

```
Hello
ello
llo
lo
o
```

The problem is that for some reason if I use `icdiff` and compare my output with that output in a text file it says that I am missing elements and that I have more spaces than it should.

Icdiff output:

```
Hello
 ello
  llo
```

As you can see this is clearly different than what I have, but if I test it on the terminal I get the expected output.

Program:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void print_array(char *p, int tamanho) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < tamanho; i++) {
        printf("%c", p[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void nova_str(char *p, char *s, int inicio, int tamanho) {
    int i;
    for (i = inicio; i < tamanho; i++) {
        s[i] = p[i];
    }
}

int main() {
    char p[1001];
    int len;
    int j;
    scanf("%s", p);
    len = strlen(p);
    print_array(p, len);
    for (j = 1; j < len; j++) {
        char *np = (char *)calloc(len + 1, sizeof(char));
        nova_str(p, np, j, len);
        print_array(np, len);
        free(np);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Really any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `calloc(2,sizeof(char))` you're always allocating 2 bytes of memory, even though you're using up to `len+1` bytes.

Comment: ok i corrected that but it still gives me that error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the `nova_str` function: you use the same index into the source and the destination, so the destination array still starts with `initcio` null bytes which are printed by the `print_array` and appear as spaces on your system. The array is initialized to all bits zero by `calloc()`.

Here is a much simpler version:

```c
#include <stdio.h> 

int main() {
    char p[1001];
    if (scanf("%1000s", p) == 1) {
        for (int i = 0; p[i] != '\0'; i++) {
            /* print the word starting at offset i */
            printf("%s\n", p + i);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks man it worked probably i was complicating it a lot, but to be fair im new at programming with pointers

Comment: @MartimCorreia: my pleasure :) Your solution was a bit complicated, but not illogical.  You can fix `nova_str` by writing `s[i - inicio] = p[i];` and you should modify `main()` by passing the correct number of characters to print: `print_array(np, len - j);`.  Then you would figure there is no need to make a copy and you can just call `print_array(p + i, len - i);`. Further simplifying, you would print the string portion directly as I did since the portion it null terminated. Simple solutions do not always appear immediately. Keep learning from practice and examples.

Answer (score 0):

calloc() is setting the memory to zero, so you are printing null characters in print_array() when it should be spaces. Replace those null characters with spaces there and this is solved, although I think there is an easier way to achieve what you are trying to do.

If you don't want the letters to be prepended by spaces, add an `if (p[i] == '\0') continue;` before printf() in print_array() instead.